# How to make thread-safe HashMap without locking `get()` method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I asked on interview a question: how to implement getter and setter for exclusive writing to `HashMap` and non-exclusive reading. Suppose following code:

```
public class MyClass {

     private HashMap map = new HashMap();


      // HOW TO implement Getter and Setter for exclusive writing and non-exclusive reading
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=xy+problem). It's hard to imagine that not having a locking get method is an actual requirement. Much more likely, you think you need this to meet some actual requirement, which you're not telling us. So every time suggestions come up, you tell us you can't use them. Presumably because they don't meet your actual requirement, whatever it is. Please just tell us what you're actually trying to do and what your actual requirements are.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I edited post, please review.

Comment: You could just use a [`ReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). Take the write lock for the put operation and a read lock for get operation. Write locks are exclusive while the read locks are not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this

```
class MyClass<K, V> {
    private HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
    private ReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private Lock rl = rwl.readLock();
    private Lock wl = rwl.writeLock();

    public V get(Object k) {
        rl.lock();
        try {
            return map.get(k);
        } finally {
            rl.unlock();
        }
    }

    public V put(K k, V v) {
        wl.lock();
        try {
            return map.put(k, v);
        } finally {
            wl.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but can you provide example without `Lock` and `ReentrantReadWriteLock` objects? I can easier understand if your example will use only synchronization primitives, like `synchronized` keyword and `private final Object mutex = new Object();` Thanks

Comment: I am afraid it's impossible, you cannot do non-exclusive lock with synchronization primitives.

Comment: @MyTitle You won't be able to achieve non-exclusive reading with `synchronized` methods. ReadWriteLock definitely makes sense here.

Comment: `ReentrantReadWriteLock` is the right tool like this answer expressed, never thought of that, at least not at a simple use case, I use them a lot to read (long operation) and write into the cache, so if I'm reading from a DB for example, I don't want another thread reading the same value from the DB, instead, lock write, write to cache, and allow readers to continue in memory.

Comment: But in this case, why lock while reading?? @MyTitle needed a map with exclusive lock while writing and not while reading. Please explain

Comment: @deejay Read locks are not exclusive to other read locks. Only write locks are exclusive to reads and other writes.

Answer (score 8):

`ConcurrentHashMap` uses a lock striping strategy: it has (with default settings) 16 locks, each guarding 1/16th of the hashmap buckets.

Simply using `volatile` would not really help as some operations need to be atomic and `volatile` only gives visibility guarantees.

An alternative is to completely synchronize the map (like in [`Collections.synchronizedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) or `Hashtable`), but the performance of such a strategy under high contention is significantly worse - it might be good enough depending on your use case.

---

An alternative to Evgeniy's proposal is a sort of "copyonwritemap" - it will not be as efficient in most scenarios:

```
class MyClass<K, V> {
    //note: map needs to be volatile to completely remove synchronization
    //at the getter level
    private volatile Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public V get(Object k) {
        return map.get(k);
    }

    public V put(K k, V v) {
        synchronized (lock) { //for exclusive writing
            Map<K, V> newMap = new HashMap<K, V> (map); //copy map
            V value = newMap.put(k, v);
            //volatile guarantees that this will be visible from the getter
            map = newMap;
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THanks, but I can't use `Collections.synchronizedMap`.  Please, can you explain more deeper about this statement: `Simply using volatile would not really help as some operations need to be atomic`. Which operations must be atomic? Can  immutable objects help me with it?

Comment: @MyTitle For example, if you have more than one item in a bucket, they are stored as a LinkedList - so when you `put`, you need to find the right bucket, check if there are some items in there, in which case you need to add a node to the list. These steps need to be atomic (imagine that the list only contains one other node which gets removed concurrently for example).

Comment: @MyTitle You should explain why you can't use `ConcurrentHashMap` or `Collections.synchronizedMap`, and what sort of contention your map will experience (number of threads, typical read/write ratio)